# Can a StaleStateObjectException ever be thrown from a single thread?

Tags: hibernate, grails

We are using Grails and Hibernate.  We are getting an `org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException` in our logs.  I see this can happen because of optimistic lock failure.  Fine.  However, I want to ensure this can never happen from multiple updates from the same thread.  I mean never ever.  Is there any corner case where there is multiple updates to the same hibernate entity but all from the same thread that can cause this exception?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try but I would expect this error from this code:

```
 Foo foo1 = session.get(Foo.class, 1);
 Foo foo2 = session.get(Foo.class, 1); // same ID

 foo1.setBar(1);
 foo2.setBar(2);

 session.saveOrUpdate(foo1);
 session.saveOrUpdate(foo2); // Should throw an error
```

This can happen, for example, when you have complex helper objects that work on the same entities.

Comment: I thought Hibernate ensured that when you `get` the same id more than once from the same session you get the same (`==`) object back?

Comment: @Aoron Digulla how do you get the hibernate session in grails?

Comment: @IanRoberts: It should but I'm not sure on what this depends and how clever it is.

Comment: @BreakoBreako: Take my answer with a grain of salt. The basic idea is that you get two copies of the same entity, modify both independently and then try to save them. In my example, `session.merge()` would probably work.